# Rewriting a route method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

so I have this:

```
match car_dealers/years/:id , to: 'car_dealers#years , via: :get
```

Is there anyway I can rewrite it and write it with that `resource` or `resources` syntax?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Is car_dealers the resource? What is the action doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
resources :car_dealers do
  match 'car_dealers/years/:id' => 'car_dealers#years', :via => :get
end
```

More information on routes and resources can be found on *[this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)*.

Comment: so we just copy pasted that inside a resources block ?

Comment: @user1899082 What does your routes code look like around your `match` statement?  (Could that be added to the question above?)